# there is possible to related a related field?

Tags: field, odoo

there is possible  to related a related field ?
I did 
1st object

```
_columns = {
        'sale_price_unit': fields.related('sale_line_id','price_unit',string='Prix de vente',type='float', store=True, readonly=True),
        }
```

the other object

```
_columns={
        'sale_price_unit': fields.related('procurement_id','sale_price_unit',string='Prix de vente',type='float', store=True, readonly=True),

        }
```

the value of the 2nd object alwayse **equal 0.0 !!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
_columns={
        'sale_price_unit': fields.related('procurement_id','sale_line_id','price_unit',string='Prix de vente',type='float', store=True, readonly=True),

        }
```

Comment: thanks brother it work fine after I alter the table stock_move and dorped the column sale_unit_price from stock_move then UPDATE DB, now it's perfect (y)